# How do I completely remove a large swath of git commits?

Tags: git

I have a repo that looks like this:

```
A--B--C------F--G   H--I--J--K---------O--P
       \    /                 \       /
        D--E                   L--M--N
```

I want to eliminate commits A..G. I don't care about expunging specific files or folders, I don't want to revert my commits, I want those commits to be gone from history. I've tried various incantations of `filter-branches` and `rebase` but I can't seem to get git to do what I want.

Comment: That looks like unrelated history. Are you trying to delete a branch?

Comment: It is unrelated history, with many branches of its own

Answer (score 0):

you can do interactive rebase (`rebase -i`) and squash (`s` in the interactive commit session) and then `push -f` to rewrite history.

Note that it will break this repository for everyone else who has this repo cloned. They will have to re-clone, potentially losing their work in progress. So it is kind of an anti-pattern.

Comment: i think `rebase -i` and instead of squash, actually delete the lines of the commits he wants gone.  however, all the commits down the line will have new commit hashes, so OP will need to understand the implications here.